# Questions about the Chow varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

In Lecture 21 of Joe Harris's famous textbook "Algebraic geometry: a first course", he introduced the concept of Chow varieties. In Theorem 21.2, he says that the open Chow variety has functorality in some sense. I tried to translate the original statement into scheme-theoretic language as follows:

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field (of arbitrary characteristic). A variety is a reduced separated finite type $K$-scheme. Let $X$ be a projective variety and let $L$ be a very ample line bundle on $X$. Then the functor from (Quasi-projective varieties)$^{op}$ to (Sets) as below can be represented by a quasi-projective variety $\tilde{C}_{k,d}(X)$ (the open Chow variety):
$$
S \mapsto \left\{
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
  F\subseteq X\times S\text{ is a closed}\\
  \text{subvariety of }X\times S\\
\end{array}
\;\left|\;\;
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
  \text{$\forall s\in S(K)$, the fiber $F_s\subseteq X$ has a}\\
  \text{reduced open dense subset, and $F_{s}$} \\
  \text{is of pure dimension $k$ and degree $d$} \\
\end{array}
\right.
\right\}
$$

Remark 1: The functorality is given by "$F\subseteq X\times S\mapsto F_{S',\text{red}}\subseteq X\times S'$" where $S'\rightarrow S$ is a given morphism of quasi-projective varieties, and the degree is calculated by intersecting with the line bundle $L$.

Remark 2: The reason that I guess this result is characteristic-free, is the sentence "We should also say that starting in Lecture 18 we will go back to an
essentially characteristic-free approach." at the beginning of Lecture 15.

My questions are as follows:

1. Did I get a right form of Theorem 21.2 (together with Exercise 21.4)? I'm a little bit worried about the characteristic (please see the next question).
2. There are some modern approaches about the Chow schemes in for example Chapter 1 of János Kollár's book "Rational curves on algebraic varieties". But it seems that this concept does not behave quite well in positive characteristic. Could you please say some words to help me understand why the things go wrong in positive characteristic? Can I understand it in this way, that although the open Chow variety can represent a functor in positive characteristic (as above), things go wrong if we consider the whole Chow variety?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  You can read more about this in the first chapter of "Rational curves on algebraic varieties" by J'anos Koll'ar.  The seminormalization of the reduced scheme of the Chow scheme is covariant in an appropriate sense.  There is a functoriality on the level of the Chow scheme as well.  A good source is the thesis of David Rydh, as well as his later articles.

Comment: @jason: Thank you! I have noticed Rydh's articles, but I'm still more concerned about the (more elementary) statement in Harris's book. It seems that the seminormal condition on the base is crucial in modern approaches (especially for the positive charcteristic case), but Harris's statement has the advantage that it allows the base to be an arbitrary quasi-projective variety (which makes it more convenient for my application). However, I didn't find any result similar to Harris's statement in the literature...

Comment: ...Does it can be covered by the modern approaches? Or could you please provide more clues to help me understand it? Thank you!

Comment: I am guessing what you want.  If you include an ample divisor class as part of your data, then there is an alternative approach by Mumford (in “Geometric Invariant Theory”), by Knudsen-Mumford, and by Fogarty.  Please also be advised, there are mistakes in textbooks sometimes.  Joe, I and others once spent a few weeks solving a problem that Joe had included in an undergrad course when it turned out to be harder than expected.

Comment: @jason: OK, thank you. In fact, I'm just looking for an affirmative answer (and some explanation towards for example, why a "generically reduced family" in Definition 21.1 can induce a regular map from the base to the open Chow variety) to my Question 1. I'm somehow convinced that this result should be true, because in (3.5,3.7.1) and especially (3.14) of Kollár's new book "Families of varieties of general type", he said that the seminormal condition of the base might be removed if one only considers geometrically reduced cycles (which somehow matches to the open Chow variety)...