# Questions about the Chow varieties, II

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, moduli-spaces

This question is closely related to my previous [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461310/questions-about-the-chow-varieties).

Recently, I find another version of the open Chow variety in János Kollár's book [Families of varieties of general type](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Ekollar/FromMyHomePage/modbook-final.pdf). I guess that (3.5) and (3.7.1) in the book might imply the following statement, which is similar but not exactly the same to the statement in my previous question.

**Statement**:
Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field (of arbitrary characteristic). A variety is a reduced separated finite type $K$-scheme. Let $X$ be a projective variety and let $L$ be a very ample line bundle on $X$. Then the functor from (Seminormal varieties)$^{op}$ to (Sets) as below can be represented by a seminormal quasi-projective variety $\text{Chow}_{k,d}^{\circ}(X)$ (the open Chow variety):
$$
S \mapsto \left\{
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
  F\subseteq X\times S\text{ is a closed}\\
  \text{subvariety of }X\times S\\
\end{array}
\;\left|\;\;
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
  \text{$\forall s\in S$, the fiber $F_s\subseteq X_{k(s)}$ has a}\\
  \text{geometrically reduced open dense} \\
  \text{subset, and $F_{s}$ is of pure dimension} \\
  \text{$k$ and degree $d$; and the morphism} \\
  \text{$F\rightarrow S$ is universally open.} \\
\end{array}
\right.
\right\}
$$

Remark: The functorality is given by "$F\subseteq X\times S\mapsto F_{S',\text{red}}\subseteq X\times S'$" where $S'\rightarrow S$ is a given morphism of seminormal varieties, and the degree is calculated by intersecting with the line bundle $L$.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is the statement above true/does it can be easily deduced from some theorems in the literature?
2. The requirements of the family $F\subseteq X\times S$ in the statement above are seemingly more than those in the statement of my previous question. My question is, does they in fact coincide? (I think they coincide at least when the dimension $k=0$.)
3. (Less important) In view of (3.14) in the book, I would like to ask that does the two "seminormal"s in the statement above can be dropped?

Thank you very much!

Comment: OK, now I'm almost confident that the statement above is indeed a special case of (3.7.1). Please tell me if I'm wrong.